# How to import eclipse project ,libs and dependancy in studio android

Tags: android, eclipse, dependencies

I am very new on using android studio. I am having one eclipse project having Facebook SDK, Google play service, and some other libs as dependencies of my project. I want to ask how to import that project in studio? I have made gradle file of my project but when i import gradle file in studio Facebook and GCM service error occurs. Please can some body tell me the steps so i can import and run project in studio?

Comment: You can find it by simple google search...here is link for migrating eclipse project to android studio
http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/sdk/installing/migrate.html
Also if there are any errors then let us know errors so any one can give solution

Answer (score 1):

Migrating from Eclipse to Android Studio requires that you change the structure of your development projects, move to a new build system, and use a new user interface. Here are some of the key changes you should be aware of as you prepare to migrate to Android Studio:

1. Project files
2. Manifest settings
3. Dependencies
4. Test code
5. User interface
6. Gradle-based build
7. systemDeveloper
8. tools versioning

At first please read this article [Migrating to Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/sdk/installing/migrate.html) And [Demo](http://www.lynda.com/articles/eclipse-into-android-studio)

Now for your requirement add this in your

> build.gradle

```
  dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.+"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a new blank Android Studio project to set up the directory structure and boilerplate. Most of your traditional Eclipse files would go in the `app/` directory. Then You'll need to update your `app/build.gradle` file with your external dependencies as well as tell gradle to pick up any other jars in your `app/lib/` directory, e.g. add:

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.+"
}
```

You also might need to make a couple more changes to the gradle file for GCM https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client.