# Importing an existing Eclipse android project into Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been given a task to import an existing eclipse android workspace to Android studio. I tried every possible way but the problem now is that the workspace I've been given is a large scale project and it contains multiple inter-related projects and libraries. 
At first, android studio couldn't find the android manifest file which I solved fixing the android facets. Doing so, generated new errors which are about the resources used in `AndroidManifest.xml` file like `@string/app_name`. How should I import the complete workspace?
**The project is working completely fine in eclipse without a single error.**

Any help or suggestion in this regard will be highly appreciated.

```
Information:Using javac 1.7.0 to compile java sources
Information:Compilation completed with 6 errors and 0 warnings in 23 sec
Information:6 errors
Information:0 warnings
G:\pgWorkspace\Pocketglobe\AndroidManifest.xml
    Error:Error:line (35)Android Resource Packaging: [pgWorkspace] G:\pgWorkspace\Pocketglobe\AndroidManifest.xml:35: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/app_icon').
    Error:Error:line (35)Android Resource Packaging: [pgWorkspace] G:\pgWorkspace\Pocketglobe\AndroidManifest.xml:35: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@android:string/app_name').
    Error:Error:line (35)Android Resource Packaging: [pgWorkspace] G:\pgWorkspace\Pocketglobe\AndroidManifest.xml:35: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme').
    Error:Error:line (109)Android Resource Packaging: [pgWorkspace] G:\pgWorkspace\Pocketglobe\AndroidManifest.xml:109: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@string/app_id').
    Error:Error:line (112)Android Resource Packaging: [pgWorkspace] G:\pgWorkspace\Pocketglobe\AndroidManifest.xml:112: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').
    Error:Error:line (118)Android Resource Packaging: [pgWorkspace] G:\pgWorkspace\Pocketglobe\AndroidManifest.xml:118: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@android:string/google_APIKEY')
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31823713/how-to-import-eclipse-project-libs-and-dependancy-in-studio-android/31824005#31824005

Answer (score 0):

1.First export your all projects into gradle build  with eclipse 
make sure you have latest ADT and SDK in eclipse.

first select generate Gradle Build
[image: first select generate Gradle Build]

2.add all your projects of work space into gradle build 
[image: Select Your Project.]

Then follow instruction. that generate your gradle Build.
remember your export location.you need to locate while importing in Android studio.

3.start Android Studio File > New > Import Project 
or in welcome screen you can select import Project.

and follow steps that android Studio ask for Gradle Setting.

For [more](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-from-eclipse-projects) information

1.[Link 1](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-from-eclipse-projects)

2.[Link 2](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you please describe your second step?

Comment: @SyedDany check Updated ans.

Comment: Hey man you are simply a genius. 
I've done as told but the problem still exists. In the very start it gives an error which says AndroidManifest.xml file not found.
I fixed it by going to File > Other project Settings > facets > ManifestFile location. After doing so, Android studio gives me few more new errors which cant find the resources stated in the manifest file. `no resource found for @string/app_name` which i checked, is there in the string.xml file.

Comment: @SyedDany can you attache screen shot/add error. and show me your project structure and Gradle file.